# strlcpy or memcpy?

Tags: c

I know strcpy is not secure when dealing with buffers, however in my code i have this

```
static char    buf[HUGE_BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
char servername[200];
int length = 0;
char *out = NULL;
        length = strlen(buf);
        out = alloca(strlen(servername) + length + 5);
        length = strlen(servername);
        strcpy(out, servername);
        out[length] = ' ';
        out[length + 1] = 0;
        strcat(out, buf);
```

If I change strcpy to strlcpy and use a sizeof for arg3, the output is garbled. Is there an easier way than using memcpy (which looks like I might have to do?) Im trying to avoid using insecure functions like strcpy and friends. Is there an easier way to accomplish the above with less copying of functions, and strnlens/alloca?

Comment: strcpy's insecurity has nothing to do with "buffers". it's insecure because it depends on well-formed null-terminated strings. forget a null terminator and strcpy will happily copy half the universe until it randmoly finds some other null char.

Comment: Is `length` and `len` supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: Yes, I was filling in this stuff manually. len is length (sorry!)

Comment: 'I was filling in this stuff manually' -- **Please don't do that**. Post actual code that you have compiled and run.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you usually should not use sizeof on a character array (though I could see using it as the last parameter to strnlen in my code below).  sizeof(servername) gives 200, sizeof(buf) gives you HUGE_BUFFER_SIZE+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HUGE_BUFFER_SIZE 4096

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  static char buf[HUGE_BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
  char servername[200];
  int target_len, servername_len, buf_len = 0;
  char *out = NULL;

  strcpy(buf, "this is my test buffer!");
  strcpy(servername, "127.0.0.1");

  /* Notice the uses of strnlen.  Each of these fixes the maximum number of characters that will be scanned. */
  servername_len = strnlen(servername, HUGE_BUFFER_SIZE+1) + 1;
  buf_len = strnlen(buf, 200) + 4;
  target_len = servername_len, buf_len;

  if ((out = alloca(target_len)) == NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE; /* alloc failed, die quickly! */

  /* At this point, you've measured the length of servername and buf using strlen, so it should really be impossible to run beyond the length of your buffer, but we're going to be careful, anyway */
  out[0] = '\0';
  strncat(out, servername, servername_len);
  strncat(out, buf, buf_len);

  printf("%s\n", out);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(barring a copy/paste error, or different libraries on your system and a cross-platform screwup on my part, you should be able to paste this into a file, compile it, and run it, and see "127.0.0.1this is my test buffer!" as the output)

Note that all of the str functions, whether strcpy, strcat, strncpy, or strlcpy, drop a null terminator onto the end of any string they create.  The only time you need to manually put on a null terminator is when you are starting a brand new string, as I did with the statement "out[0] = '\0'".

Also, note that I used strnlen and strncat, not strlcat.  I cannot tell from the documentation the difference between strlcat and strncat except in what the function returns.

Anyways, you should be able to avoid buffer-overrun security holes just be clearly bounding all of your function calls.  strncpy and strncat bound how much data you will copy.  strnlen bounds how long the system will search for a '\0'.

---

Edit: my original solution actually had an error that valgrind revealed.  I was not initializing either buf or servername.  While something else seemed to be magically initializing buf, valgrind reported that calling strcat with servername as the target was causing decisions to be made based on uninitialized data.  *doh*.

Since I'm not sure why I was calling strcat to initialize my variables with string literals, I switched to strcpy.  That, of course, is perfectly safe here because I have hard-coded into the application exactly the string I'm copying into the variable.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that everything we have written here FAILS MISERABLY if we start dealing with strings outside the basic ascii set.  If you have UTF-8 or UTF-<anything> encoded data, or if you are using abstract unicode, you will have '\0' in your character stream and have to totally switch to a different set of functions.

Comment: If you have a UTF-8 string, it will not contain '\0'. That's the point of UTF-8 : supporting Unicode without having to rework every single piece of code dealing with strings

Answer (score 2):

It might be simpler to just use `snprintf()`:

```
char out[1000];  // Or however large you need.
int len = snprintf(out, sizeof(out), "%s %s", servername, buf);
if (len >= sizeof(out)) {
    // Result would have overflowed the buffer and has been truncated.
}
```

Note `>=` instead of `>` in the conditional.

`snprintf()` returns the length of the text written, not including the terminating null byte.  So, if the returned value is equal to the buffer size, that means the final character got truncated (because `snprintf()` always null-terminates the resulted string).

Comment: Pedantic code would use `if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof(out)) {` as `len < 0` is an _encoding error_.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you must be getting garbled output is because you may be using sizeof for `out`. But, `out` is not a buffer and is a pointer and so you may be effetively passing only 4 (or whatever is the size of the pointer) as the size to the third argument, there by not copying more than 3 characters and rest is the unintialized memory which shows you garbage

You can try using strncpy and pass the length to be copied as the third argument.

Comment: Is there a way I could /possibly/ remove the pointer for *out and simply use a char itself? Or simply do a copy of 'out' into a char (as long as it's not NULL)?

Comment: strncpy is invariably the wrong answer, other than for its original use, which was to zero-pad fixed length fields (specifically, 14-byte file names in early unix directory entries). It's wrong because a) it does not NUL-terminate the destination and because b) it NUL-pads the destination to its entire length, which is nearly never necessary and is unnecessarily time-consuming.